# After some weird flash out, I can't login to wmii any more, how to fix it?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, tty

I've been using wmii on Ubuntu14.04(virtual machine on win7) for months.

I got popped out to the login interface several times due to some wired mouse click action.

But today this happened, I couldn't login to wmii any more. I'm stuck at the interface like

[image]

The bottom yellow bar is the command area for wmii. but it has no response when I press `Mod` + `p`

I restart my machine, and even reinstalled wmii, but every time I tried to log in to wmii, I'm stuck at that interface. By the way, I login to wmii from the login interface, where I can choose between Gnome and wmii. I can login to gnome normally

How to fix this?

Comment: Reviewers: the edited answer makes it clear that this Q might indeed be useful for future users - that's why I retracted my Close vote.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the problem was caused by some extra resize configuration which I copied from internet to enable keyboard resize.

After deleting these configurations, I can log into wmii again.

**Be aware that reinstalling wmii won't refresh your local wmii config,** which is under `$HOME/.wmii/`

So if you encounter a similar problem, check your wmiirc and recover its original status.